# Resolution Rule of Inference From Derived Clause

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

My discrete math textbook says this:

“Solution: We can rewrite the premises (p ∧ q) ∨ r as two clauses, p ∨ r and q ∨ r. We can also replace r → s by the equivalent clause ¬r ∨ s. Using the two clauses p ∨ r and ¬r ∨ s, we can use resolution to conclude p ∨ s“

But I’m confused. If we derive the original premise to get p ∨ r and q ∨ r, can we just ignore the premise q v r if we’re able to infer a resolution from the other clause?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, we have derived the conclusion from the original set of premises.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you don’t always have to use all of that information inherent in the premises. If part of it is sufficient to get to the conclusion, then that’s just fine! Indeed, sometimes you can infer the conclusion from a strict subset of the premises: whole premises are just mot being used. But as long as you can get to the conclusion, it’s a valid argument.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your answer!!

Comment: @JessicaHerlitz You are welcome!